# Firebase cloud function inline code editor

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to reduce the cold start time on my firebase cloud function. I have around 30 functions that use different imports.

As in an info video mentioned, it's better to use only the imports that your cloud function needs.

In the google cloud console, you can view your code.

[image: Cloud console function]

But if I scroll down the LIB/INDEX.JS contains all my functions.
There's an option to edit the code.

Would it be harmful to delete all other functions & the imports that aren't used (for that specific function in LIB/INDEX.JS) with the inline code editor? (Even though I made my functions via typescript in visual studio code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not be harmful to the other functions.  If you are editing the code of a Cloud Function in the console, it will not modify the code used by other Cloud Functions.  Each function is fully isolated from each other, even if they share the same deployment. The code is copied between each function.

That said, editing functions deployed by the Firebase CLI should only be done in experimentation. When it comes time to actually deploy code, you should again use the CLI to finalize everything.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But the function itself will still work correctly (assuming there aren't bugs in the edits)? + do I only have to edit the LIB/INDEX.JS or also the typescript?

Comment: You will not be able to edit the TypeScript to make functional changes.  The Firebase CLI compiles the TS into JS.  Cloud Functions doesn't know anything about TS.